# MS Access Rotate query by PIVOT TRANSFORM

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have developed a database in MS Access 2013.
I need to make a report from two tables: inventory_type, inventory ( and some experience in T-SQL)

inventory table:

```
id
inv_type(FK of inventory_type.id)
inv_name, etc.
```

inventory_type table:

```
id
type_name
```

I made simple query with GROUP BY:

```
SELECT it.type_name AS [Inventory name], Count(i.ID) AS Quantity
FROM inventory_type AS it INNER JOIN inventory AS i ON it.ID = i.inv_type
GROUP BY it.type_name;
```

Result of this query is :

```
Inventory Name | Quantity
VideoCamera         3
PC                  5
.....
```

But the result should be like this:

```
Quantity | VideoCamera | PC
Quantity |     3          5
```

I've tried to do like this:

```
TRANSFORM Count(it.ID) AS Quantity
SELECT "Quantity"
FROM inventory_type AS it INNER JOIN inventory AS i ON it.ID = i.inv_type
GROUP BY it.type_name
PIVOT it.type_name;
```

But result is not quite what I expected:

```
Quantity | VideoCamera  |  PC
Quantity        3              
Quantity                    5
```

Could someone help me out on this, can't really understand ms access semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `type_name` from `GROUP BY` clause:

```
TRANSFORM Count(it.ID) AS CountOfQuantity 
SELECT 'Quantity' AS Quantity
FROM inventory_type AS it INNER JOIN inventory AS i ON it.ID = i.inv_type 
GROUP BY 'Quantity' 
PIVOT it.type_name;
```